# why composite compoment does not invoke in the <h:datatable/>

Tags: jsf, composite-component

I have a compoment which has a method-signature attribute. It can be activated, but if I put it in a `<h:datatable> <h:column/>` and trigger this component, it does not work.

When I just refresh this page again or when I put it in another place it can invoked successfully. I would be grateful if somebody can tell me why!

this is my code

```
<h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">op:</f:facet>
                    <h:commandLink value="alter" action="#{userSession.alterAction}"
                        rendered="#{userSession.user.power.powerID == 1}">
                        <f:param name="beanId" value="#{book.bookID}" />
                        <f:param name="class" value="#{BookBean}" />
                    </h:commandLink>
                    <h:commandLink action="#{userSession.detailAction}" value="detail"
                                   rendered="#{userSession.user != null}">
                        <f:param name="beanId" value="#{book.bookID}" />
                        <f:param name="class" value="#{BookBean}" />
                    </h:commandLink>
                    <h:commandLink action="#{bookAction.bookDelAction}"
                        onclick="return confirm('are you sure?')" value="delete"
                        rendered="#{userSession.user.power.powerID == 1}">
                        <f:param name="beanId" value="#{book.bookID}" />
                    </h:commandLink>
                </h:column>
```

this manageredBean #{bookAction} is requestScope when i click one of this operation,just like delete ,it doesnot work at all. but if i put the 'delete' commandlink out of `<h:datatabel/>`  .it can invoke backing method successfully. it is so upset!

who can tell me whether `<h:datatable/>` can Shielding the  .i found if i put these code in a `<h:form/>` .it can invoke too! cound you can tell me the reason!

Comment: So, a normal command button works?

Comment: i test it which just is a nomal button .if i does not put it in the <h:datatable/> it can work very well!

Comment: So, the problem is not the composite component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to preserve exactly the same data model (i.e. the one which you have referenced by the `value` attribute of the `<h:dataTable>`) in during the request of the form submit as it was during the request of displaying the initial form. The symptoms indicate that you're using a request scoped bean and that the loading of the data model is based on some request parameter which is missing during the form submit and/or the loading is not being done during bean's (post)construction.

Putting the bean in the view scope and/or rearranging the data loading logic should fix it.

Comment: i use postConstruct method indicate that i doesnot mising my parameter

Comment: Then the `rendered` attribute apparently evaluated `false` during processing the form submit. Verify that as well.

Comment: thank you very much ! i know your means ,the reason is that because the JSF need to restored view .so the datamodel is mising .and the rendered is false.And the action can not invoke though i click it .but this project i use weld @name to identify manageBean .so it seems that the @pageScope is not useful.shoud i must post all data to backing data .is any good idea?